# All my mixer states gone - FL Studio

Tags: effects, missing

When i reopened my project all my mixer channels (besides the Main one) and their effects racks were completely purged. The effects volume states are still there, and when the sound plays the volume indicators still "dance" as they receive imput, but none of the plugins are there, and their name, color and track volume are reset to default.
I removed the VST folder just to make sure there's no plugin that cause this, but it's not the case.
The backups are saved the same. No effects.
I have an older backup, it does have the effects, but is just half of my project, so the newer ones are not there stil.

I would appreciate it so much if someone would take the time to help me with this...!
Thank you very much!

[image][image]

Comment: Would this not be better asked of FL's support?

Comment: I can't make an account on their forum for the momment...

Answer (score 1):

I found the cause of the problem: Low disk space (~30 MB). It seems that the .flp projects need more to save all their data.

I fixed the problem: i used the existing backup effects and i rebuild the rest from scratch.

Thank you for your time!